# Make instances converge in geometry nodes

Tags: instances

I'm working on a Draw Pencil tool to draw locks of hair using Geometry Nodes. Each strand is an instance juxtaposed along a Mesh Line with some degrees of randomization.
[image]

What I can't seem to figure out is how to make the ends converge to one another.
[image]

I can achieve the result by converting the object to mesh in object mode and scaling the endpoints in edit mode, but I would like to automate the process.

[image]

Comment: Maybe instead of scaling them together you could work with something like proximity in _Geometry Nodes_. The following tutorial by CrossMind Studio might be a bit too long and covering lots of things you don't need, but I've linked to the timestamp where the proximity is used to attract flower stems, perhaps this is helpful: [09-Geometry Proximity-Geometry Nodes (Fields) For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9flmk1sHBnk&t=1112s)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have a better grasp now of the Geometry Proximity node and Set position node. The solution I came up with is to use the initial bezier curve as target for geometry proximity, and use it to set endpoint position of the instance on points group. The result is a group of curves is then use to create a lock of hair